# iPhone OpenGL ES: glReadPixels not working

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, picking, glreadpixels

I trying to implement a simple picking function using glReadPixels however when I click on an object that is 1 colour, I get different values back depending on where I clicked on that object?  There not special lighting etc?  Whats going on?  Sometimes all zeros are returned.  I turned everything off (textures etc) but still no joy.

I thought this functions returns the colour of the pixel you click on?

```
- (void)getPixelColour:(CGPoint)point {

    Byte pixelColour[4];
    glReadPixels(point.x, point.y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixelColour);

    NSLog(@"%d %d %d", pixelColour[0], pixelColour[1], pixelColour[2]);

}
```

Update:  added this to fix it:

```
glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, __viewport );   
point.y = (float)__viewport[3] - point.y;
```

Comment: Is your CGPoint in Touch coordinates?  Are you rendering OpenGL upsidedown?  Remember that OpenGL renders from the bottom up and touches come in from the top down.

Comment: Good point, yes cgpoint is the touch point, so I have to invert it somehow?

Comment: Ed Post your comment as a answer as you helped to fix the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, _*viewport );

point.y = (float)*_viewport[3] - point.y;